# How can I really change the IP address?

Tags: vpn, facebook

I am from Serbia. When I visit Facebook or Instagram with my VPN (Avast) on and location set to Japan, the pages are still in the Serbian language.

When I change location to Japan I guess it should display in Japanese language? It look slike they can somehow detect VPN and see the real IP address.

Is there a way I can really change my IP address?

Comment: There is a browser preference for the language which gets sent on each request. Sites often use this to find out which language you want. VPN does not change such settings. VPN also does not remove existing cookies which store other preferences.

Comment: If you are asking how to change your IP, then this is off topic, but I'm not sure that is what you are asking. Can you clarify please.

Answer (score 4):

One of the primary things used for websites to determine which language to send the page back in is the Accept-Language header.  Modern browsers set this header for all requests based on your preferred language settings.  It is probable that even though you are using a VPN with an IP address in Japan, your browser is still sending the Accept-Language header with a preference for Serbian

Answer (score 2):

Facebook can (most likely) *not* detect your IP behind VPN.
But they don't need to.

There's your account, various browser settings, cookies and many more things allowing to recognize you.

If you want to be anonymous, there's much more to it than using VPN or even Tor. To start with, get rid of your account. Block all local data and scripts. Randomize your user agent. Don't visit the sites you used frequently before. Install something to delay mouse clicks. etc ...

Comment: so facebook know this is me when i use vpn and login with diferent account or don't know?

Comment: @nikola99 You're using the same computer (can be detected), where you used your old account before  (can be detected), with the same behaviour like frequently visited sites, mouse click rythm etc. (can be detected) ... so yes, they can know.

Comment: Some concretion into what they *actually* use would be welcome here.  If I were Facebook, I would hardly rely on click rhythm alone, and although they *could* be using that, I don't honestly think they are.  My first suspicion would be cookies, but I have not investigated.

Comment: @tripleee I don't know what they use how, and I'm sure they won't tell us (or lie). And of course it will be a combination of many things, not mouse clicks alone. ... About investigating, how would that help? Just because removing cookies could reset the language, that doesn't mean that they can't detect that it's you.